# I made lots of trades on Etherdelta - one came in but cant find it

Tags: etherdelta

I made a number of trades on etherdelta - all lowball bids.  One came in but I cant remember which tokens I bid on - was about 20 but have no idea.  Is there an easy way to see all past trades?  I dont want to have to click on every coin and wait..... Went through about 40 so far no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go here,  https://etherscan.io/ , insert your adress used for Etherdelta, it will then give the blocks that were used for Etherdelta.

Insert those blocknumbers here -> https://etherdelta.github.io/trades.html  and you should be able to find your trades pretty easily.

Let me know if this worked out for you.

Comment: Found it  :-) Thank you so much - you just saved me hours and hours!!!!!!!!!!!